# How many significant figures can a number have in CSS?

Tags: css

My question is, simply, how many (non-zero) decimal places can I include in a value I use in a CSS stylesheet before the browser rounds the number when interpreting it?

NOTE:  I am aware that any decimal pixels are rounded (differently by different browsers) because the screens cannot display sub-pixel units.  What I am asking is *before* that rounding takes place, what number of decimal places will be retained to begin performing the final browser rendering calculations/roundings.

Comment: why do you have to use decimals in CSS ?

Comment: I've seen a lot of CSS wireframes which make use of the "Golden Ratio" which is an irrational number (non-repeating, infinite decimal) which I would like to get as accurate as possible in percentage dimensions.

Comment: For example, a grid with cells whose lengths are 161.8033989% their height

Comment: This is entirely implementation-dependent. CSS itself places no arbitrary restrictions - it has no reason to.

Comment: To confirm BoltClock's comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#percentage-units

Comment: In addition, those percentages will have to be transformed to pixels to draw on your screen and at some point the extra precision at the sub-pixel level won't have an effect. In your example, if we assumed a height of 768 pixel, the difference between 161.8033989% and 161.8% is 0.02 pixels, which the browser might have some trouble differentiating for you...

Comment: You're right, but I'm thinking that that .02 could make the difference of rounding up or down, and I'd like to get it as accurate as possible so the rounding scheme is as precise as possible.

Comment: What exactly is your goal for having this degree of accuracy?

Comment: it's purely idealistic.  I am trying to have expressions render finite values whose ratios (also finite) are as close to an infinite value as possible.  I know, it sounds crazy, I think i'm gonna close this thread... :-)  but not before I post what could be a temporary solution to satisfy my madness.

Comment: This is still an interesting question to me, although it may have no practical implications.  The question, apart from my implementation, begs an answer, but for the meantime I've decided to create a grid system using rectangular cells with fixed width ratios of 89px/55px, 55px/34px, 34px/21px and other combinations to approximate 1.618033989....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be it truncation or rounding, in an ideal world, neither of these things should happen. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers) simply says that a numeric value may either consist of

- one or more digits, or
- any number of digits, followed by a period for the decimal point, followed by one or more digits.

The spec even accounts for the fact that the leading zero before the decimal point in a value that's less than 1 is not significant and can thus be omitted, e.g. `opacity: .5`. But there is quite simply no theoretical upper limit.

But, due to implementation limitations, browsers will often "round" values for the purposes of rendering. This is not something you can control other than by changing the precision of your values, and even so, this behavior can vary between browsers, for obvious reasons, and is therefore something you cannot rely on.